# Perl readdir warning - Name "main::DIR" used only once: possible typo

Tags: perl

I have a script which lists the possible file in particular directory. The code works fine, but how to avoid this warning?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $logpath = "C:/Users/Vinod/Perl/Log";

opendir(DIR, $logpath);
while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {

    next unless (-f "$logpath/$file");
    print "FILENAME:$file\n";

}
closedir(DIR);
```

Warning shows while compiling or running the script is:

```
$ perl -cw log_fetch.pl
Name "main::DIR" used only once: possible typo at log_fetch.pl line ...
log_fetch.pl syntax OK
```

Comment: It appears to be a weird side-effect of using `use autodie;`. You shouldn't be using global vars needlessly anyway. Use a lexical var (`my $DIR`), and the problem becomes moot.

Comment: @ikegami Are you suggesting not to use `use autodie;`. Yes its fixed when I modified the line to `opendir(my $DIR, $logpath); while (my $file = readdir($DIR)) {`.

Comment: @toolic Yes I'm on windows - Cygwin.

Comment: Re "*Are you suggesting not to use `use autodie;`.*", No, I'm recommending use a lexical var

Comment: Re "*Yes I'm on windows - Cygwin.*", hmmm. Cygwin is a unix emulation. It's not really Windows.

Comment: @toolic, Re "*Could be a windoze thing. I don't see it on linux.*", I see it on Linux. I think it only happens with newer versions of autodie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a weird side-effect of using `use autodie;`.

The warning can be silenced as follows:

```
sub x { *DIR }  # Silence spurious "used only once" warning.
```

However, you are needlessly using a global variable (`*DIR`). It would be far better to use a lexical variable, and this would moot the problem.

```
opendir(my $DIR, $logpath);
```